# Regex looking for a specific HTML tag to mark the end of the string I'm looking for

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I have a Regex expression that finds, in a HTML formatted string, the start of a substring that begins with 'http', 'https' or 'www'...

This regex statement does that but gives me everything from the start till it sees the first occurrence of white space:
\b(?:https?://|www.)\S+\b

Can this be modified to stop at a specific expression like, in my case `</span>`

So my HTML string is consistently formatted like this:

```
<div style="font-size:12pt;font-family:Consolas;"><p style="color:#0000FF;font- 
    size:14pt;margin:0;">This is hilarious:</p><p style="font-family:Consolas;font- 
    size:9.5pt;margin:0;"><span style="color:#0000FF;font-family:Consolas;font- size:14pt;">https://media.giphy.com/media/lCP95tGSbMmWI/giphy.gif</span></p><p style="color:#0000FF;font-family:&quot;Microsoft Sans Serif&quot;;font-size:8.5pt;margin:0;"><br></p></div>
```

I just want the return of the string:
https://media.giphy.com/media/lCP95tGSbMmWI/giphy.gif

Can this Regex statment be modified to stop when it sees the  expression:

var linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```cs
var linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)[^\s<>]+", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:https?://|www\.)` - `http://`, `https://` or `www.` string (note the escaped `.`that matches a literal dot)
- `[^\s<>]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace, `<` and `>`  chars.